# Wrong dates on Google Chart API Line Graph

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-visualization

So I am trying to map Tide times on a line graph using Google's Chart API.
However, the points plotted on the Graph don't correspond to the correct date and time values.

The data is in the form date time (x-axis) and height of tide (y-axis).
I'm not sure if I am creating the date time value correctly, or it the API is just doing something weird.

For instance, the last date in the tideTimes array is for the 1st of November, but the Graph is showing data points for December, you can see this behaviour in image below. I added the code below to allow you to recreate these errors.

If anyone could tell me what I am doing wrong, it would be greatly appreciated.
[image: showing wrong data points on google chart api]

```
    <html>
      <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
          google.setOnLoadCallback(drawWeekChart);
          function drawWeekChart() {

            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('datetime', 'Date');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Wave Height (Meters)');
            var tideTimes = [
                [new Date(2012, 10, 29, 05, 44, 00, 00), 9.12],
                [new Date(2012, 10, 29, 11, 47, 00, 00), 1.62],
                [new Date(2012, 10, 29, 18, 01, 00, 00), 9.23],
                [new Date(2012, 10, 30, 00, 01, 00, 00), 1.55],
                [new Date(2012, 10, 30, 06, 16, 00, 00), 9.20],
                [new Date(2012, 10, 30, 12, 16, 00, 00), 1.58],
                [new Date(2012, 10, 30, 18, 33, 00, 00), 9.21],
                [new Date(2012, 10, 31, 00, 29, 00, 00), 1.54],
                [new Date(2012, 10, 31, 06, 46, 00, 00), 9.21],
                [new Date(2012, 10, 31, 12, 45, 00, 00), 1.60],
                [new Date(2012, 10, 31, 19, 04, 00, 00), 9.12],
                [new Date(2012, 11, 01, 00, 58, 00, 00), 1.59]
            //  new Date( YYYY, MM, DD, HH, MM, SS, MS), height]
                        ];
            data.addRows(tideTimes);

            var options = {
                title: 'Tide Times',
                smoothLine: true,
                width: 984,
                height: 600
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('tide_chart_week'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
          }

        </script>
      </head>
      <body>
    <div id="tide_chart_week" stye="float:left; height:800px; background:blue;"></div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Month must be a integer b/w 0-11.

Check the Date() constructor docs [0]

> month Integer value representing the month, beginning with 0 for
>   January to 11 for December.

Just change your `tideTimes` variable accordingly

```
 var tideTimes = [
            [new Date(2012, 9, 29, 05, 44, 00, 00), 9.12],   // october
            //.....
            [new Date(2012, 10, 01, 00, 58, 00, 00), 1.59]   // november
 ];
```

Also, you might want to change your chart's horizontal axis format to show friendlier dates

```
 var options = {
     /*.. current options ..*/
     hAxis:  {format:'MMM d, y'}
 };
```

[image: Example]

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/jaimem/F4Gzr/1/

---

[0] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: The OP has not specified a whether the charts are for a specific region, so it's not clear whether US–centric dates are friendlier or not (given that most of the world doesn't use them). The year seems to be redundant, so either 29-Oct or Oct-29 is probably suitable.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, it is odd that dates are between 0-11. Considering days start at 1, it all seems a bit inconsistent. I agree the date time on the hAxis needs to be more legible, that was something I was going to think about once I got the graph actually working.

Comment: @jonhurlock—JavaScript dates were made to be consistent with Java dates, where months are indexed from 0 to 11. They even copied the Java Y2K issue where `getYear()` only returns a two digit date (and hence why `getFullYear()` was introduced).

Answer (score 1):

As jm pointed out, in ECMAScript months are zero based so:

```
new Date(2012, 10, 31, 19, 04, 00, 00)
```

is 31 November 2012, which creates a date for 1 December 2012 (since November only has 30 days) and:

```
new Date(2012, 11, 01, 00, 58, 00, 00)
```

is also 1 December, 2012.

Answer (score -2):

```
<div id="tide_chart_week" stye="float:left; height:800px; background:blue;"></div>
```

Note the use of stye instead of style !